# manage my members by Their Working speed

Tags: algorithm

I need an **algorithm**(for using in php) to manage our members

I have some members, that Preparing content for me,

They Preparing content and when completed, **wait** for me to go and get their content (member couldn't refer to me) and after i refer to them and get content, they work for new content, and not defined time of next content will complete(every 1 hours,i can **only** go to the 1 member)

member working are completely separated !

My members have difference in work speed, some members are fast and some members are slow

If i go to the member with FIFO method (Consider all member,equally speed), some members that are fast , wait a long time , and for some other members that are slow ,i go to them ineffectual.

At the first, i don't know members speed, and should Consider all member have equal speed until i detect their speed

i logging my going to the member like this:

```
╔════════╦════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║user id ║ last visit ║ work is complete? ║
╠════════╬════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ 1      ║ 8:00       ║     Yes           ║
║ 2      ║ 9:00       ║     No            ║
║ 3      ║ 10:00      ║     No            ║
║ 4      ║ 11:00      ║     Yes           ║
║ 1      ║ 12:00      ║     Yes           ║
║ 2      ║ 13:00      ║     No            ║
║ 3      ║ 14:00      ║     No            ║
║ 4      ║ 15:00      ║     Yes           ║
║ 1      ║ 16:00      ║     Yes           ║
║ 2      ║ 17:00      ║     Yes           ║
║ 3      ║ 18:00      ║     Yes           ║
║ 4      ║ 19:00      ║     Yes           ║
╚════════╩════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

In above example, user 1,4 are fast and user 2,3 are slow

How to prioritize all member as fast user visited more times and slow user visited less times,

And how to detect which user is a better choose for next visit?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with two simple queues. The `busy` queue and the `waiting` queue. (Note that in an operating system, there are actually more queues, simplest of which is the `blocked` queue).

The `busy` queue holds tasks (or work member if you want) that already have a job. The `waiting` queue holds tasks that have finished their job. Depending on your initial configuration, one of the queues is full and the other empty (For example, if initially no one has a job, the `busy` queue is empty and `waiting` is full).

Now your task assignment algorithm is as easy as follows:

```
Every 1 hour

    If waiting.empty       // If no one previously-known to be without a job
        Linearly search busy and find who has finished their job
        Add them in order to waiting while removing them from busy
        (So, search busy from head to tail and add to waiting from tail)

    If !waiting.empty      // If now there is someone without a job
        Assign a job to waiting.head and put it in the end of busy
```

This algorithm will make sure there is no starvation by keeping the tasks in order. So for example if two tasks are very fast and the others take forever, then the algorithm keeps alternating between the two fast tasks (instead of only giving one of them jobs all the time).

---

Now you may actually want to give the fastest most jobs even if he gets all the jobs and the others none (unlikely, but I don't know your goal). In this case, you need some book-keeping to rank the tasks. For example the time the task was assigned to them and the time they finished it. This means that the linear search in the algorithm above should be done every hour (instead of only when `waiting` is empty).

Accordingly, `waiting` becomes a max-priority-queues where the priority is higher the faster a task is. So the fastest task would always show up first if it's not busy.

If you want to somewhat compensate for starvation using this algorithm, you can add an `age` to each task which gets increased every time they are in `waiting` and not get a job. The priority would then be combination of how fast a task is and what is its age. If you have a linear combination of the two, you don't need to rearrange the priority-queue when the tasks age since the ordering remains the same (as they all age by the same amount at the same time).

---

**Edit:** Even though I don't understand why in php you can go to only one member per scheduling time, I have your solution anyway.

Since you don't have any information regarding the speed of the members, assigning each of them tasks is inevitable at first. That's the learning phase. So whatever structure holds the tasks, at first it should act like a FIFO.

Gradually as you understand the speed of the members, you would need to better arrange them in the queue.

Well, this with a very similar algorithm to the section above (where priority-queues are used), you can achieve this.

First, for each member keep three values: `work_time_start`, `min_work_time` and `max_work_time`. They represent your understanding of how long it takes for the member to finish its task. As you assign work to a member, you set its `work_start_time`. Every time anywhere in the algorithm you visit that node, based on whether it has finished his task or not, you update its `min_work_time` or `max_work_time`. Initially `min_work_time` is 1 and `max_work_time` is infinity.

Now you can have three (priority-)queues; `waiting`, `busy`, `maybe_busy`. The first two queues are as before. The third is for tasks that you are not sure if they have finished their task or not. In other words, it contains tasks that their current execution time is between `min_work_time` and `max_work_time`.

Note: I'm assuming you can **go** to a task only once, but you can check your book-keeping as much as you want (which may contain imprecise data). Is that ok?

So here's the new algorithm:

```
Every one hour

    // Note: busy is a min-priority queue on work_start_time + min_work_time
    while busy.head satisfies (time() - work_start_time >= min_work_time)
        remove busy.head and add it to maybe_busy

    // Note: maybe_busy is a min-prioiry queue on work_start_time + max_work_time
    while maybe_busy.head satisfies (time() - work_start_time >= max_work_time)
        remove maybe_busy.head and add it to waiting

    // Note: waiting is a min-priority queue on min_work_time
    If !waiting.empty
        take waiting.head
        assign a task to it
        put it in busy

    Else
        go to maybe_busy.head
        If it is still busy
            update its min_work_time
            remove from maybe_busy and add to busy
            sorry, but you can't assign a task this hour
        If it is not busy
            remove from maybe_busy
            update its max_work_time
            assign a task to it
            put it in busy
```

The algorithm may look complicated and I may have introduced some errors, but the concept is quite simple. The tasks have three states:

```
                  WAITING
                 /       \
               BUSY -- MAYBE BUSY
```

`WAITING` tasks are for sure free, so you can always assign tasks to them. `BUSY` tasks are for sure busy, so you don't need to go to them.

`busy` is a min-priority queue on `work_start_time + min_work_time`, which means looking at its head, you get the first member that may have finished its job. If so, it is moved to `maybe_busy` (and repeated until the head is still surely busy)

`maybe_busy` is a min-prioiry queue on `work_start_time + max_work_time`, which means looking at its head, you get the first member that surely has finished its job. If so, it is moved to `waiting` (and repeated until the head is still unknown whether it's busy or not)

The two first `while` loops are book-keeping and don't require you to actually go to a member. They are managed based on the information you have gathered so far.

Then, you check `waiting`. If it is not empty, then you have a member that is surely available. You just go to it and give it a task. Just put him in `busy` because you just gave him a job.

If `waiting` is empty, you have to unfortunately go to a member that you suspect most would have finished its job (head of `maybe_busy`) and ask if he's finished or not.

If he is not finished, you update its `min_work_time` so in the future you know that he is slower than you previously thought. You then need to add him to `busy` because for sure he is busy now (you just asked him!)

If he is finished, you update its `max_work_time` so in the future you know that he is faster than you previously though. You then assign it a task and add it to `busy` because you just gave him a job.

At first, this algorithm would keep putting every one in `maybe_busy` and going to them one by one, so at first it acts like a FIFO. After the first iteration however, it would have a basic idea of how long each task may take and would have a better guess of which task it should go to first. After each visit, the statistics are refined.

Note: this algorithm still suffers from starvation. If the algorithm figures out the super fast member, it will constantly give him jobs. If you don't want starvation for other tasks, you would again need to introduce `age`.

Comment: The matter is perhaps complicated a bit, if I understand the question correctly, by the fact that he can't just do a "free" linear search through the busy queue, but can only check one worker per hour for completion. That probably means that both steps have to be merged into one if the algorithm shouldn't wait time senselessly. (Of course, the scenario that checking for completion should be about as time consuming as finishing a task sounds quite artificial.)

Comment: @MikeHartl, you're right. I misinterpreted this sentence: `i logging my going to the member like this:` as "I log in ..." so I thought with a simple log-in he gets all that information. Ok, I'll try to think of a more proper solution.

Comment: @ Mike Hartl ,Yes we can only chack or get completed job on time per hour,(only one of both), really i changed the main purpose for better understand

Comment: Sorry, i think that previous post is better for understanding, now this is the really problem,if in some section i don't give  
enough explanation, please tell me to give more explanation

Comment: @odr_m9611, I gave another algorithm based on my current understanding of the problem. Give it a look.

Comment: @Shahbaz, Thank you very much for your help , i go for Implementing it